# g++ cannot static link libmongcxx(r3.0.2) but dynamic link works

Tags: c++, mongodb, c++11, gcc, mongo-cxx-driver

I use the example code from mongodb site to show the problem here. OS: ArchLiux, c++ is  a link to g++

> [dean@dell_xps_13 ~]$ c++ --version c++ (GCC) 6.2.1 20160830 Copyright
>   (C) 2016 Free Software Foundation, Inc. This is free software; see the
>   source for copying conditions.  There is NO warranty; not even for
>   MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

code is in test.cc file

```
#include <iostream>

#include <bsoncxx/builder/stream/document.hpp>
#include <bsoncxx/json.hpp>

#include <mongocxx/client.hpp>
#include <mongocxx/instance.hpp>

int main(int, char**) {
  mongocxx::instance inst{};
  mongocxx::client conn{mongocxx::uri{}};

  bsoncxx::builder::stream::document document{};

  auto collection = conn["testdb"]["testcollection"];
  document << "hello" << "world";

  collection.insert_one(document.view());
  auto cursor = collection.find({});

  for (auto&& doc : cursor) {
    std::cout << bsoncxx::to_json(doc) << std::endl;
  }
}
```

First compile it to object file:

> c++ -g -std=c++11 -I../include -I/usr/include/bsoncxx/v_noabi
>   -I/usr/include/mongocxx/v_noabi  -Wall -o test.o -c ./test.cc

Link it without -static works:

> c++  test.o -o test -static-libgcc -static-libstdc++ -L/usr/lib
>   -lpthread -lmongocxx -lbsoncxx -lboost_log -lboost_log_setup -lboost_system -lboost_thread -lboost_filesystem

This can run and print out some messages:

```
[dean@dell_xps_13 mongo-cxx-driver-r3.0.2]$ ./test
{
    "_id" : {
        "$oid" : "58218e821b489308ae4411d1"
    }, 
    "hello" : "world"
}
```

Now get error with -static option

> c++  test.o -o test -static-libgcc -static-libstdc++ **-static**
>   -L/usr/lib -lpthread -lmongocxx -lbsoncxx -lboost_log -lboost_log_setup -lboost_system -lboost_thread -lboost_filesystem

Many error messages show below:

> /usr/lib/libmongocxx.a(client.cpp.o): In function
>   `mongocxx::v_noabi::client::client(mongocxx::v_noabi::uri const&,
>   mongocxx::v_noabi::options::client const&)':
>   /home/dean/work/github/mongo-cxx-driver/src/mongocxx/client.cpp:(.text+0x28):
>   undefined reference to`mongoc_client_new_from_uri'
>   /home/dean/work/github/mongo-cxx-driver/src/mongocxx/client.cpp:(.text+0x10c):
>   undefined reference to `mongoc_client_destroy'
>   /usr/lib/libmongocxx.a(client.cpp.o): In function`
>   mongocxx::v_noabi::client::operator=(mongocxx::v_noabi::client&&)':
>   /home/dean/work/github/mongo-cxx-driver/src/mongocxx/client.cpp:(.text+0x190):
>   undefined reference to `mongoc_client_destroy'
>   /usr/lib/libmongocxx.a(client.cpp.o): In function`
>   mongocxx::v_noabi::client::~client()':
>   /home/dean/work/github/mongo-cxx-driver/src/mongocxx/client.cpp:(.text+0x1c3):
>   undefined reference to `mongoc_client_destroy'
>   /usr/lib/libmongocxx.a(client.cpp.o): In function`
>   mongocxx::v_noabi::client::read_concern(mongocxx::v_noabi::read_concern)':
>   /home/dean/work/github/mongo-cxx-driver/src/mongocxx/client.cpp:(.text+0x214):
>   undefined reference to `mongoc_client_set_read_concern'
>   /usr/lib/libmongocxx.a(client.cpp.o): In function`
>   mongocxx::v_noabi::client::read_concern() const':
>   /home/dean/work/github/mongo-cxx-driver/src/mongocxx/client.cpp:(.text+0x243):
>   undefined reference to `mongoc_client_get_read_concern'
>   /home/dean/work/github/mongo-cxx-driver/src/mongocxx/client.cpp:(.text+0x24b):
>   undefined reference to`mongoc_read_concern_copy'
>   /home/dean/work/github/mongo-cxx-driver/src/mongocxx/client.cpp:(.text+0x27c):
>   undefined reference to `mongoc_read_concern_destroy'
>   /home/dean/work/github/mongo-cxx-driver/src/mongocxx/client.cpp:(.text+0x2a3):
>   undefined reference to`mongoc_read_concern_destroy'
>   /usr/lib/libmongocxx.a(client.cpp.o): In function
>   `mongocxx::v_noabi::client::read_preference(mongocxx::v_noabi::read_preference)':
>   /home/dean/work/github/mongo-cxx-driver/src/mongocxx/client.cpp:(.text+0x3a4):
>   undefined reference to`mongoc_client_set_read_prefs'
>   /usr/lib/libmongocxx.a(client.cpp.o): In function
>   `mongocxx::v_noabi::client::read_preference() const':
>   /home/dean/work/github/mongo-cxx-driver/src/mongocxx/client.cpp:(.text+0x3c3):
>   undefined reference to`mongoc_client_get_read_prefs'
>   /home/dean/work/github/mongo-cxx-driver/src/mongocxx/client.cpp:(.text+0x3cb):
>   undefined reference to `mongoc_read_prefs_copy'
>   /home/dean/work/github/mongo-cxx-driver/src/mongocxx/client.cpp:(.text+0x3fc):
>   undefined reference to`mongoc_read_prefs_destroy'
>   /home/dean/work/github/mongo-cxx-driver/src/mongocxx/client.cpp:(.text+0x423):
>   undefined reference to `mongoc_read_prefs_destroy'
>   /usr/lib/libmongocxx.a(client.cpp.o): In function`
>   mongocxx::v_noabi::client::uri() const':
>   /home/dean/work/github/mongo-cxx-driver/src/mongocxx/client.cpp:(.text+0x463):
>   undefined reference to `mongoc_client_get_uri'
>   /home/dean/work/github/mongo-cxx-driver/src/mongocxx/client.cpp:(.text+0x46b):
>   undefined reference to`mongoc_uri_copy'
>   /home/dean/work/github/mongo-cxx-driver/src/mongocxx/client.cpp:(.text+0x49c):
>   undefined reference to `mongoc_uri_destroy'
>   /home/dean/work/github/mongo-cxx-driver/src/mongocxx/client.cpp:(.text+0x4c3):
>   undefined reference to`mongoc_uri_destroy'
>   /usr/lib/libmongocxx.a(client.cpp.o): In function
>   `mongocxx::v_noabi::client::write_concern(mongocxx::v_noabi::write_concern)':
>   /home/dean/work/github/mongo-cxx-driver/src/mongocxx/client.cpp:(.text+0x504):
>   undefined reference to`mongoc_client_set_write_concern'
>   /usr/lib/libmongocxx.a(client.cpp.o): In function
>   `mongocxx::v_noabi::client::write_concern() const':

....

> /usr/lib/libbsoncxx.a(oid.cpp.o): In function
>   `bsoncxx::v_noabi::oid::to_string[abi:cxx11]() const':
>   /home/dean/work/github/mongo-cxx-driver/src/bsoncxx/oid.cpp:(.text+0x139):
>   undefined reference to`bson_oid_to_string'
>   /usr/lib/libbsoncxx.a(oid.cpp.o): In function
>   `bsoncxx::v_noabi::oid::get_time_t() const':
>   /home/dean/work/github/mongo-cxx-driver/src/bsoncxx/oid.cpp:(.text+0x1ea):
>   undefined reference to`bson_oid_get_time_t'
>   /usr/lib/libbsoncxx.a(oid.cpp.o): In function
>   `bsoncxx::v_noabi::oid_compare(bsoncxx::v_noabi::oid const&,
>   bsoncxx::v_noabi::oid const&)':
>   /home/dean/work/github/mongo-cxx-driver/src/bsoncxx/oid.cpp:(.text+0x24f):
>   undefined reference to`bson_oid_compare'
>   /usr/lib/libbsoncxx.a(oid.cpp.o): In function
>   `bsoncxx::v_noabi::operator<(bsoncxx::v_noabi::oid const&,
>   bsoncxx::v_noabi::oid const&)':
>   /home/dean/work/github/mongo-cxx-driver/src/bsoncxx/oid.cpp:(.text+0x2af):
>   undefined reference to`bson_oid_compare'
>   /usr/lib/libbsoncxx.a(oid.cpp.o): In function
>   `bsoncxx::v_noabi::operator>(bsoncxx::v_noabi::oid const&,
>   bsoncxx::v_noabi::oid const&)':
>   /home/dean/work/github/mongo-cxx-driver/src/bsoncxx/oid.cpp:(.text+0x30f):
>   undefined reference to`bson_oid_compare'
>   /usr/lib/libbsoncxx.a(oid.cpp.o): In function
>   `bsoncxx::v_noabi::operator<=(bsoncxx::v_noabi::oid const&,
>   bsoncxx::v_noabi::oid const&)':
>   /home/dean/work/github/mongo-cxx-driver/src/bsoncxx/oid.cpp:(.text+0x36f):
>   undefined reference to`bson_oid_compare'
>   /usr/lib/libbsoncxx.a(oid.cpp.o): In function
>   `bsoncxx::v_noabi::operator>=(bsoncxx::v_noabi::oid const&,
>   bsoncxx::v_noabi::oid const&)':
>   /home/dean/work/github/mongo-cxx-driver/src/bsoncxx/oid.cpp:(.text+0x3cf):
>   undefined reference to`bson_oid_compare'
>   /usr/lib/libbsoncxx.a(oid.cpp.o):/home/dean/work/github/mongo-cxx-driver/src/bsoncxx/oid.cpp:(.text+0x42f):
>   more undefined references to `bson_oid_compare' follow collect2:
>   error: ld returned 1 exit status

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `-static` flag forces the linker to accept only static libraries and not any shared libraries. In other words it does not require a dependency on dynamic libraries at runtime in order to run.
Most likely `mongocxx` has some dependencies.
To achieve static linking requires that the archive (.a) versions of your libraries exist on the system.

The another possible issue is that the order of static libraries in the linker command line does matter, so that might also be an issue if there is a dependency on different static libs. The linker will process the libraries in order as they are in the command line, and from each static lib it will only pull those symbols that are required (with as much information as the linker has at that time)

Use [nm](https://linux.die.net/man/1/nm) . That will give you the symbol names.

Comment: In my system, I have .a and .so files.

ls /usr/lib/libmongocxx.* -alh
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 568K May  6  2016 /usr/lib/libmongocxx.a
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   21 May  6  2016 /usr/lib/libmongocxx.so -> libmongocxx.so._noabi
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 310K May  6  2016 /usr/lib/libmongocxx.so.3.0.0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   20 May  6  2016 /usr/lib/libmongocxx.so._noabi -> libmongocxx.so.3.0.0

Comment: Yeah, you have `libmongocxx.a` static lib but also you need to have (.a) versions of dependency libraries

Comment: You probably need to add -lbson and -lmongoc to get the libmongoc and libbson dependencies.

Comment: libmongocxx depends on mongo c driver, I forget this. using nm can see the mongoc_client_new_from_uri function is there, google this, it is a mongo c driver function.
But did not find  the libmongoc.a file in my system. I am searching ....

Comment: Here is the github [link](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-c-driver). Before installation try running `./configure --enable-static`, that should trigger the generation of the static lib

Comment: Thanks, when using enable-static to compile & install mongoc driver, I got new err msgs:
`
$ c++ test.o -o test -static-libgcc -static-libstdc++ -static -L/usr/lib -lpthread -lmongocxx -lbsoncxx -lmongoc-1.0 -lbson-1.0 -lboost_log -lboost_log_setup -lboost_system -lboost_thread -lboost_filesystem
/usr/lib/libmongoc-1.0.a(libmongoc_1_0_la-mongoc-client.o): 
/usr/lib/libmongoc-1.0.a(libmongoc_1_0_la-mongoc-init.o): In function `_mongoc_do_init':
mongoc-init.c:(.text+0x25): undefined reference to `sasl_set_mutex'
`

Comment: It seems you are missing [libgsasl](https://www.gnu.org/software/gsasl/)

Comment: I guess the question is answered. Now I need to find the libsasl2.a file in my archlinux, or compile it myself.
Thanks everyone here.

Comment: @DeanChen `undefined reference to 'sasl_set_mutex' ` looks like an LDAP dependency.  If you have a dynamically-linked version of your application working, running `ldd` on it will list all the dependent libraries you will need static versions of.

Comment: ldd /usr/lib/libmongocxx.so show there is a libsasl2.so.3 => /usr/lib/libsasl2.so.3 (0x00007f728e48c000) dependency. But I have not found the .a file in my Arch.