# Can't use static lib of mongo-cxx-driver on Linux

Tags: c++, mongodb, c++11, gcc, mongo-cxx-driver

So I follow the official tutorial for the installation : https://mongodb.github.io/mongo-cxx-driver/mongocxx-v3/installation/

Neverless, I can't use the produced libraries as static.

So I managed to compile the C version of the driver as described, I've enabled the flag *--enable-static=yes* with the ./configure before doing *make && sudo make install* and I got the *libmongoc-1.0.a* and the *libbson-1.0.a* which are static. So this far, everything it's alright.

Then I have done the cxx version of the driver, except that there is no configuration file as in the C version. So I've juste done a

```
cmake -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release -DBSONCXX_POLY_USE_BOOST=1 -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr/local
```

from the build folder, followed by a *make && sudo make install*

So I got the *libmongocxx.a* and the *libbsoncxx.a*, but when I try to compile with them, I can't run the binary because I got the following error :
*error while loading shared libraries: libmongocxx.so._noabi: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory*

So I understand that is because there is some symbols missing and then I need to use the shared library to run the binary but I don't want this to happend, I want the symbols within the binary that I can run it without any LD_PRELOAD.

Any suggestions ?

Comment: You haven't mentioned how you compiled your application.  Please post a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org) so we can try to replicate your issue.  In this case, please include the exact command lines (or a shell script) and output as well.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue in an Ubuntu 16.04 and I run a apt-get update & apt-get upgrade and the problem was solved.

It seems that there were some update to the compiler and some libraries that prevent some test from reaching the shared libraries.

Answer (score 0):

I have [a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40485621/g-cannot-static-link-libmongcxxr3-0-2-but-dynamic-link-works), and solved, now I compiled and run my binary with static libs successfully.

I write my build script using newlisp, but the static link options are very helpful, I paste it here.

```
c++  /to/your/path/site/code/back_end/builder/object/files1.cc.o ... /to/your/path/site/code/back_end/builder/object/files10.cc.o -o bin/site -static-libgcc -static-libstdc++ -L/usr/lib -lpthread -l:libmongocxx.a -l:libbsoncxx.a -l:libmongoc-1.0.a -l:libbson-1.0.a -lrt -lssl -lcrypto -lsasl2 -l:libboost_log.a -l:libboost_log_setup.a -l:libboost_system.a -l:libboost_thread.a -l:libboost_filesystem.a -lcppcms -lbooster -lcurl -ljsoncpp
```